# Logical test fails in program with unexpected output

Tags: c, turbo-c

I have the folliwing code:

```
void main() 
{  
    int a=30,b=40,x;
    x=(a!=10) && (b=50);  
    printf("x=%d",x);
}
```

Here in the result I get `x=1`. In `&&` operator the condition true only when both are true here the first is true i.e a not equal to 10 , but second is `b=50` which is wrong then also the value of `x` is 1 in out put. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Check out the difference between "=" and "=="!

Comment: My God, they still make Turbo C?

Comment: actually I have just started coding so I am strting from the basics @Charlie Martin

Comment: Use a compiler which warns about such construct. Every modern compiler will do.

Comment: Please do not deface your own question.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, change

```
 ... && (b=50);
```

to

```
 ... && (b == 50);
```

Otherwise, the *value* of `b`, after the *assignement*, will be considered as the second expression of the `&&` operator.

Comment: Or even better:  `50 == b`

Comment: @KIIV Yoda, eh? Sure you can do it. :)

Answer (score 4):

The second comparison is actually an assignment.  It should be:

```
x=(a!=10) && (b==50);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the assignment operator `=` rather than the equivalence test `==` operator against `b`.

**Fixed Code Listing**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a=30, b=40, x;
    x = ((a!=10) && (b==50));
    printf("x=%d",x);
}
```

---

A good strategy to prevent this in the future is to swap your `LVALUE` and `RVALUE`, so your code looks like this:

```
    x = ((10 != a) && (50 == b));
```

If you adhere to the above style, if you make the same mistake in the future, you would end up with:

```
50 = b
```

Which would trigger a compilation error, since you can't assign a variable `RVALUE` to a constant/literal `LVALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Expression `(b=50)` has logical value `1` (`true`), not `0` (`false`).